# Callback в роли ViewModel-и

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, mvvm

Скажите пожалуйста Callback на клиенте может выступать в роли ViewModel-и с точки зрения MVVM? Просто все его методы они получаются как бы события которые вызываются с сервера. В то же время никакую особую логику свойственную только сервису в него не впихнешь. (во всяком случае в моей задаче) Так почему бы и нет? Что толку что я в нем насоздаю событий на каждую функцию и буду ловить их во ViewModel-и? Может проще просто использовать сразу его как ViewModel? Ну если (как обычно) кому то что-то не понятно будет (я уже предчувствую) то вот вам пример. Обычный чат. На калбэке вызываются функции вроде: клиент подсоединился / клиент отсоединился, получено приватное / публичное сообщение и т.п. Они тупо как события. Никаких особых действий тут в калбэке не происходит. Просто добавляются сообщения в отображаемый список или добавляет / убирается пользователь из списка подключенных.

Comment: Когда у нас были сообщения уровня _Presentation_, то очень удобно было делать _ViewModel_ handler-ом, можно сказать callback-ом. _VM_ регламентировалась несколькими интерфейсами - handler-ами для сообщений. В вашем случае, говорят, что лучше не надо, но, думаю, что в некоторых других случаях, почему бы нет.

Comment: В общем то я уже решил вопрос давно. Все таки не стал я его ViewModel-ю делать. Во первых чтобы не нарушать паттерн, а во вторых как выяснилось если сделать просто каждый метод по событию это хоть и геморно, но потом пользоваться удобно. Особенно если разбивать на каждое окно по ViewModel-и то можно в  разных ViewModel-ях по необходимости подвязываться на разные события калбэка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотря что вы называете callback'ом.

В WPF есть довольно строгие требования к VM: это должен быть класс, реализующий `INotifyPropertyChanged` (или наследующийся от `DependencyObject`), который обязан бежать в главном потоке (я не рассматриваю довольно сложный случай многопоточного UI).

Обычно callback — это всего лишь функция/делегат, который такими свойствами не обладает, и может быть вызван в *произвольном* потоке.

Может быть, вам подойдёт комбинированный вариант: VM-класс, в котором есть callback-методы, бегущие в контексте вызывающего кода, которые перенаправляют информацию в главный поток, в котором и бежит остаток класса.

Кроме того, вся WCF и её callback'и в частности является строго модельным объектом, так что я бы очень не рекомендовал пытаться втиснуть WCF во ViewModel-ный класс. Я бы разделил код на две части: VM-класс отдельно, в VM-уровне, а WCF и его callback'и оставил в модели. Таким образом у вас разделяются ответственности: часть, бегущая в контексте вызывающего кода, уходит в модель, а VM живёт по своим правилам.